# How to give the id to the html textbox?

Tags: html, textbox, html-helper

How to give the id to the html textbox?

My html tag looks like this

```
<%=Html.TextBox("username")%>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What language/platform is this? Please tag appropriately!

Answer (score 4):

```
<%= Html.TextBox("username",new { ID = "<put id here>"}) %>
```